# Rendering CombinedChartView using Swift Charts

Tags: swift, ios-charts

I am using https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts and able to successfully render LineChartView.  However, trying to render a very simple CombinedChartView renders as a blank chart.  Also, any touch event will output "CGAffineTransformInvert: singular matrix."

```
@IBOutlet weak var chartView: CombinedChartView!

var lineData = [ChartDataEntry]()
lineData.append(ChartDataEntry(x: Double(0), y: drand48()))
let lineDataSet = LineChartDataSet(values: lineData, label: "line")

var barData = [BarChartDataEntry]()
barData.append(BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(0), y: drand48()))
let barDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: barData, label: "bar")

let combinedData = CombinedChartData(dataSets: [lineDataSet, barDataSet])
chartView.data = combinedData
charView.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Am I totally missing something here?
Thank you.

Comment: How do you add it to your view?

Comment: @sdasdadas: I use the Storyboard to hook it up.  I have placed a UIView and then change the type to CombinedChartView and changed the module to "Charts"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I totally forgot about the demo that comes along with Charts.  Basically, we need to set the data sets for each type of graph; then assign the data sets to the CombinedChartData.

```
@IBOutlet weak var chartView: CombinedChartView!

var lineData = [ChartDataEntry]()
lineData.append(ChartDataEntry(x: Double(0), y: drand48()))
let lineDataSet = LineChartDataSet(values: lineData, label: "line")
let lineChartData = LineChartData(dataSets: [lineDataSet])

var barData = [BarChartDataEntry]()
barData.append(BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(0), y: drand48()))
let barDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: barData, label: "bar")
let barChartData = BarChartData(dataSets: [barDataSet])

let combinedData = CombinedChartData()
combinedData.lineData = lineChartData
combinedData.barData = barChartData
chartView.data = combinedData
charView.notifyDataSetChanged()
```